# How to perform an action according to different select option value?

Tags: html, django

I want to show the prices in selected currency from INR,USD,EUR etc. But each currency has a different api key.
Plz suggest how can I change api key value based on the selected option.

```
<select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3 output" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
        <option onclick="getCurrency()" selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">inr</option>
        <option value="2">usd</option>
        <option value="3">eur</option>
      </select>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCurrency() {
            selectElement = document.querySelector('#select1');
            output = selectElement.value;
            if (output==2){
                apidata=api2data;
                
            }
            else if (output == 3){
                apidata=api3data;
               
            }
        }
```

P.S api2data and api3data corresponding to apikeys of USD and EUR respectively.

Comment: Instead of useing ``onclick`` use ``onchange``

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use on change it should work

```js
        function getCurrency() {
            selectElement = document.querySelector('#select1');
            output = selectElement.value;
            if (output==2){
                apidata=api2data;
                
            }
            else if (output == 3){
                apidata=api3data;
               
            }
        }
```

```html
<select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3 output" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
        <option onchange="getCurrency()" selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">inr</option>
        <option value="2">usd</option>
        <option value="3">eur</option>
      </select>
```